# Concatenate NumPy arrays inplace with a conditional

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to concatenate two NumPy arrays based on one condition, so the order of the concatenation depends on that condition.

This is what I have now:

```
a = empty([2048, 1536])
    
for i in range(2048):
    if s[i]: # s[] -> array with shape (2048, 1) with ones and zeros
        a[i] = concatenate([b[i], c[i]]) # b[] and c[] -> arrays with shape (2048, 768)
        continue
    a[i] = concatenate([c[i], b[i]]) # order changes depending on condition
```

I don't know how to make this operations in only one or reducing the computation time. I want it to be as optimized as possible, but I'm new to NumPy and I don't know it well.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

i am posting the results of 4 different methods to do this, because the results are rather counter-intutive, also there is a bug in the function in the question which makes it always evaluate to true.

```py
import numpy as np
import time
s = np.random.choice(2,(2048,1))
a = np.empty([2048, 1536])
b = np.random.random((2048,768))
c = np.random.random((2048,768))

def func1(s,a,b,c):
    s = s.astype(bool).flatten()
    not_s = np.logical_not(s)
    a[s,:b.shape[1]] = b[s]
    a[s, b.shape[1]:] = c[s]

    a[not_s,:b.shape[1]] = c[not_s]
    a[not_s,b.shape[1]:] = b[not_s]
    return a

def func2(s,a,b,c):
    for i in range(2048):
        if s[i,0]:  # s[] -> array with shape (2048, 1) with ones and zeros
            a[i] = np.concatenate([b[i], c[i]])  # b[] and c[] -> arrays with shape (2048, 768)
            continue
        a[i] = np.concatenate([c[i], b[i]])  # order changes depending on condition
    return a

def func3(s,a,b,c):
    s_bool = s.astype(bool).flatten()
    not_s = np.logical_not(s_bool)
    a[s_bool] = np.hstack([b[s_bool], c[s_bool]])
    a[not_s] = np.hstack([c[not_s], b[not_s]])
    return a

import numba

@numba.njit
def func4(s,a,b,c):
    for i in range(2048):
        if s[i,0]:  # s[] -> array with shape (2048, 1) with ones and zeros
            a[i,:] = np.concatenate((b[i], c[i]))  # b[] and c[] -> arrays with shape (2048, 768)
        else:
            a[i,:] = np.concatenate((c[i], b[i]))  # order changes depending on condition
    return a

def func5(s,a,b,c):
    return np.hstack([np.where(s, b, c), np.where(np.logical_not(s), b, c)])

def func6(s,a,b,c):
    dim1 = a.shape[0]
    dim2 = a.shape[1]
    for i in range(dim1):

        if s[i] == 0:
            a[i, :dim2 // 2] = b[i, :]
            a[i, dim2 // 2:] = c[i, :]
        else:

            a[i, :dim2 // 2] = c[i, :]
            a[i, dim2 // 2:] = b[i, :]
    return a
t1 = time.time()
for _ in range(100):
    res1 = func1(s,a.copy(),b,c)
t2 = time.time()

t3 = time.time()
for _ in range(100):
    res2 = func2(s,a.copy(),b,c)

t4 = time.time()

t5 = time.time()
for _ in range(100):
    res3 = func3(s,a.copy(),b,c)

t6 = time.time()

func4(s, a.copy(), b, c)  # compile it
t7 = time.time()
for _ in range(100):
    res4 = func4(s,a.copy(),b,c)
t8 = time.time()

t9 = time.time()
for _ in range(100):
    res5 = func5(s,a.copy(),b,c)
t10 = time.time()

t11 = time.time()
for _ in range(100):
    res6 = func6(s,a.copy(),b,c)
t12 = time.time()

assert (res1 == res2).all()
assert (res3 == res2).all()
assert (res4 == res2).all()
# assert (res5 == res2).all() # still fails
# assert (res6 == res2).all() # fails
print(f"using partial slicing = {t2-t1}")
print(f"using python for loops {t4-t3}")
print(f"using full slicing {t6-t5}")
print(f"using machine code {t8-t7}")
print(f"using np.where {t10-t9}")
print(f"optimized python {t12-t11}")
```

```
using partial slicing = 1.9734187126159668
using python for loops 1.7545206546783447
using full slicing 3.3108901977539062
using machine code 1.2231426239013672
using np.where 3.1704039573669434
optimized python 1.6609220504760742
```

python loops appear to be faster than numpy slicing ... which is rather counter intutive, i am guessing because it accesses the arrays in the order the data is aligned in memory.

Edit: added other ppl answers for comparison.

Comment: I use from numpy import x, but it is true it also can generate conflicts.

Comment: @underwater i have modified my answer as a correct benchmark.

Comment: `func1` would be my first choice.  But I'm not overly surprised that `func2` is better.  `func1` has some complicated indexing that takes time.  And of course both involve a full copy.  A simple `np.hstack((b,c))` takes about the same time as `func2`.   An unconditional copy `a[:,:768]=b; a[:,-768:]=c` is about half the time.

Answer (score 1):

I think concatenate is not the correct solution and it can be solved by proper slicing:

```
import numpy as np

dim1 = 32
dim2 = 16

a = np.empty([dim1, dim2])
b = np.ones([dim1, dim2//2])
c = np.zeros([dim1, dim2//2])
    
s =     np.ones([dim1, 1])
s[:dim1//2] = 0

for i in range(dim1):
    
    if s[i] == 0:
        a[i, :dim2//2] = b[i, :]
        a[i, dim2//2:] = c[i, :]
    else:
        
        a[i, :dim2//2] = c[i, :]
        a[i, dim2//2:] = b[i, :]
```